# App Store Distribution Countries

Tags: ios, xcode, store

The apps submitted to the App Store, are they available to all countries by default? or do you have to specify the countries you want your app to be sold in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default your application will be available in all countries. but you can specify the list of countries, if you want.

Comment: Dmitry, what if you don't have a language support for a particular country? Is English going to be the Language then?

Comment: @BrentBash it depends on your default language. I suppose that English is the default language in you apps. So yes, English should be the default language for countries without localizations.